# Powershell XML Schema Validation - read schema from variable

Tags: xml, powershell, validation, xsd

I have to validate an XML against its schema using [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings] / [System.Xml.ValidationType]::Schema

(Pseudo-sample)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rootelement>
      <firstnode>(here validation error against the schema)
      </firstnode>
     </rootelement>
```

Now, it works perfectly fine if the XSD is on a file, like:

```
$readerSettings = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
$readerSettings.Schemas.Add($namespace,"c:\schema.xsd")
```

giving the correct validation error:

```
Line: 1 Offset: 202 - The element 'FirstNode' has invalid child element 'Title'. List of possible elements expected: 'Description'.
```

but using URI:

```
$readerSettings.Schemas.Add($Namespace,'https://server:port/xmlschema/Schema.xsd')
```

or StringReader:

```
$CurrentXSD=Invoke-restMethod -Uri 'http://server:port/xmlschema/Schema.xsd'
$readerSettings.Schemas.Add($Namespace,(new-Object System.IO.StringReader($CurrentXSD.OuterXML))
```

it is not working, complaining that the root element is missing.

```
Line: 1 Offset: 40 - The 'rootelement' element is not declared
```

In all 3 scenarios the XSD is always the same, of course.
Can someone please shed some light?
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post the validation error? Also, why not just pass the xsd uri directly, like `$readerSettings.Schemas.Add($Namespace,"https://server:port/xmlschema/Schema.xsd")`?

Comment: That's the point: I have a (pursposedly ill-written) xml to validate. when I do the validation using the file, the error gets detected. Using the method you suggested I get the same -non-error I got using the stringreader: Line: 1 Offset: 40 - The 'rootelement' element is not declared.

Comment: ..while of course 'rootelement' IS declared in the schema. It's just that if reading the schema from a file works as it should. Reading from URI or StringReader doesn't..

Comment: Not sure I understand - you're validating an ill-formed XML document against its intended schema and (correctly) getting a validation error? What's the problem? Sounds like it's working as intended

Comment: Using the XSD *FILE* as in the first example, I get the correct validation error, while using the XSD by URI or StreamReader I get the "Rootelement" is missing one, which is wrong. (the XSD is the same, the error can't be different)

Comment: I've re-formulated the question in order to try to make it clearer (I hope)